# Case statement with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, gridview, case

I'm using a query to get results to Gridview

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Order_Header.Id, Order_Header.Payment_Id, Order_Header.Order_No
FROM 
    Order_Header 
INNER JOIN
    Order_Shipping_Detail ON Order_Header.Id = Order_Shipping_Detail.Order_Id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    cod_orders ON cod_orders.Order_Id = Order_Header.Id
WHERE 
    Status = 2
```

However, I need to return all orders where status = 2 and orders where payment Id is cod (also status = 2) and cod_orders.Is_confirmed  = 1.

Can I use a CASE statement for this?

However, if I try doing this, I'm achieving my results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Order_Header.Id, order_Header.Payment_Method_Id,Order_Header.Order_No
FROM Order_Header INNER JOIN Order_Shipping_Detail
ON Order_Header.Id = Order_Shipping_Detail.Order_Id 
LEFT JOIN cod_orders 
ON cod_orders.Order_Id = Order_Header.Id 
WHERE Status = 2 and Payment_Method_Id != 6
UNION 
Select DISTINCT Order_Header.Id, order_Header.Payment_Method_Id,Order_Header.Order_No
FROM Order_Header INNER JOIN Order_Shipping_Detail
ON Order_Header.Id = Order_Shipping_Detail.Order_Id 
LEFT JOIN cod_orders 
ON cod_orders.Order_Id = Order_Header.Id 
WHERE Status = 2 AND cod_orders.Is_Confirmed = 1
```

Can I merge these into one query?

Comment: it is better if you provide  sample data and expected output in question

Comment: Did you tried `CASE` statement in `WHERE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could merge 2 conditions like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Order_Header.Id, Order_Header.Payment_Id,Order_Header.Order_No
FROM Order_Header INNER JOIN
     Order_Shipping_Detail
     ON Order_Header.Id = Order_Shipping_Detail.Order_Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     cod_orders
     ON cod_orders.Order_Id = Order_Header.Id 
WHERE Status = 2 and (Payment_Method_Id != 6 or cod_orders.Is_confirmed = 1)
```

Comment: It returns all the rows